# How do I select rows by their values in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a table in R with the following structure:

```
ID var1 var2 var3 .... varN
AA  1    2    1          3
AB  0.2  1    4          1
```

...

How can I select only those rows where `var1<2` and `var2<2` and `var3<2` and ... `varN<2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is `dat` the test for all elements in a row being less than 2 and retruning only those rows would be:

```
dat[ apply( apply(dat[-1], 1, "<" ,2) , 2, all ), ]
```

The logic:  the inner apply returns a logical matrix:

```
apply(dat[-1], 1, "<" ,2)
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
var1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
var2 TRUE FALSE  TRUE
var3 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
varN TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Notice that it is transposed in dimensions, since R matrices are constructed column-major order, so the outer apply needs to work on columns, hence the use of 2 as the INDEX for applying the `all` function. Testing:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="ID var1 var2 var3  varN
 BA  1  1  1  1
 AA  1    2    1          3
 AB  0.2  1    4          1", header=TRUE)

 dat[ apply( apply(dat[-1], 1, "<" ,2) , 2, all ), ]
#  ID var1 var2 var3 varN
#1 BA    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your example isn't reproducible, I made my own:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = 1:4, x2 = 2:5, x3 = 3:6, x4 = c(1,6,3,12))
#-----
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  1  2  3  1
2  2  3  4  6
3  3  4  5  3
4  4  5  6 12
```

Based on your criteria, I think we should select rows 2 and 4. This code gets that for you:

```
x[apply(x, 1, function(z) all(diff(z) > 0)),]
#-----
  x1 x2 x3 x4
2  2  3  4  6
4  4  5  6 12
```

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your criteria, I thought you wanted rows where `var1 < var2 < var3 < varN`, but Justin's answer seems to answer a different problem?

Comment: I think you're right and I just didn't gud.  I'll delete my answer.  On second read, the OP wants rows where all its values are less than 2.  so in their example no rows would be returned... I think

Comment: @Justin - I'm not sure which one of us answered the right question. I'd recommend keeping your answer since I think it's pretty nifty, and even if it's not exactly what the OP wants - shows some efficient logic implementation.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. My criteria was to select only those rows where all values are less or equal than a given value. So, removing diff function from your example I've got exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you data is in a `data.frame` DF:

```
DF[rowSums(DF) == sum(2 * dim(DF)[2]), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, there are at least two ways to do what you want (in addition to those already specified. The first is the `which()` command. Based on your query:

```
datasetname[which((datasetname$var1<2) & (datasetname$var2<2) & ... ]
```

should return the rows you want. So will

```
newdatasetname <- subset(datasetname, datasetname$var1<2 & ...)
```

Just type `?subset` and `?which` in R to find out more about these commands.

Comment: I know about this way to subset data, but the idea was to select all rows whitout using their names beacuse my dataframe is quite large and I found a little tiresome to list all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
dat[rowSums(dat[,-1] >= 2) == 0,]
```

Test:

```
dat <- read.table(text=
"ID var1 var2 var3  varN
 BA  1     1   1    1
 AA  1     2   1    3
 AB  0.2   1   4    1", header=TRUE)
dat[rowSums(dat[,-1] >= 2) == 0,]
#  ID var1 var2 var3 varN
#1 BA    1    1    1    1
```